# How to import handlebars template in controller and place it in another handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am sorry if this question is silly. I have started working on front end with ember js and I am loving it. 
I am stuck at a point where I want to import a handlebars template in ember js controllers and attach it to div.

So How to import a handlebars template in controller and populate it and place it inside another handlebars template.

Here is my controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {
    search: function() {
            alert("done");
          }
    }

});
```

here is the handlebars template:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
   <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Mark</th>
       <th>Subject</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {{#each students}}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ this.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ this.mark }}</td>
       <td>{{ this.subject }}</td>
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

I have published the code on github and url is : https://github.com/focode/emberjs2/tree/master/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to read the official tutorial again. In the tutorial, you will see that there is rarely use of the **controller**.

When you generate a router using `ember-cli`, `ember g route routeName` the correspond template is generated under template folder called `routeName.hbs` inside the template, there is a tag named `{{outlet}}` this is where the nested template goes.

For example, generate a nested route using `ember g route routeName/nestedOne` which gives you with another template called `nestedOne.hbs` inside `template/routeName/nestedOne.hbs` which actually goes inside the `{{outlet}}` in the privouse generated template `routeName.hbs`.

Ember use **convention over configuration** so that you do not need to manually import a template.

Recommend a beginner tutorial which covers a lot. It is free and update (last update is in late 2016).

https://leanpub.com/ember-cli-101

Answer (score 1):

You don't populate a template from the controller. You directly use it from the template.

For this you basically have two ways. The preferred way is to use a component. However notice, that this will give you a new, isolated context. The other way is to use the [`partial` helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_partial), which will render a template in the current context.